# Como escuchar un Beacon desde un app flutter

Tags: flutter

estoy haciendo mi primera aplicación con Flutter (Dart).

Necesito detectar la presencia de un dispositivo beacon en la cercanía de mi móvil. Estuve investigando y me encontré con 2 posibles plugins:
beacons:0.3.0
flutter_beacon:0.2.4

Mi primera duda es cual será mejor. Tiendo a pensar que la mejor opción es la segunda, porque es un plugin propio de flutter mientras que el otro es de un tercero.

Con esto en mente, agregué ese plugin a mi proyecto, y para mi alegría venía con un ejemplo de cómo usarlo. Pensé en simplemente ejecutar ese ejemplo para ver cómo era y luego integrarlo a mi aplicación, pero no me funciona.

El primer problema fue con la versión de mindSDKVersion, que en mi proyecto era 16 y en el plugin 18. 
Simplemente cambié el valor del mindSDKVersion, pero al ejecutar el ejemplo, me sale el siguiente error, y la aplicación muere.

El código en mi main.dart es el siguiente:

```
    import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_beacon/flutter_beacon.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  StreamSubscription<RangingResult> _streamRanging;
  final _regionBeacons = <Region, List<Beacon>>{};
  final _beacons = <Beacon>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    initBeacon();
  }

  initBeacon() async {
    try {
      await flutterBeacon.initializeScanning;
      print('Beacon scanner initialized');
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

    final regions = <Region>[];

    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      regions.add(
        Region(
            identifier: 'Cubeacon',
            proximityUUID: 'CB10023F-A318-3394-4199-A8730C7C1AEC'),
      );
      regions.add(Region(
          identifier: 'Apple Airlocate',
          proximityUUID: 'E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0'));
    } else {
      regions.add(Region(identifier: 'com.beacon'));
    }

    _streamRanging = flutterBeacon.ranging(regions).listen((result) {
      if (result != null && mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _regionBeacons[result.region] = result.beacons;
          _beacons.clear();
          _regionBeacons.values.forEach((list) {
            _beacons.addAll(list);
          });
          _beacons.sort(_compareParameters);
        });
      }
    });
  }

  int _compareParameters(Beacon a, Beacon b) {
    int compare = a.proximityUUID.compareTo(b.proximityUUID);

    if (compare == 0) {
      compare = a.major.compareTo(b.major);
    }

    if (compare == 0) {
      compare = a.minor.compareTo(b.minor);
    }

    return compare;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    if (_streamRanging != null) {
      _streamRanging.cancel();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Flutter Beacon'),
        ),
        body: _beacons == null
            ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
            : ListView(
          children: ListTile.divideTiles(
              context: context,
              tiles: _beacons.map((beacon) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(beacon.proximityUUID),
                  subtitle: new Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Flexible(
                          child: Text(
                              'Major: ${beacon.major}\nMinor: ${beacon.minor}',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0)),
                          flex: 1,
                          fit: FlexFit.tight),
                      Flexible(
                          child: Text(
                              'Accuracy: ${beacon.accuracy}m\nRSSI: ${beacon.rssi}',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0)),
                          flex: 2,
                          fit: FlexFit.tight)
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              })).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Y esto es lo que aparece cuando lo ejecuto:

> Launching lib\main.dart on SM J500M in debug mode...
>   Initializing gradle...
>   Resolving dependencies...
>   Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
>   Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
>   Syncing files to device SM J500M...
>   I/BeaconManager( 7818): BeaconManager started up on pid 7818 named 'cl.teknopartner.beacon_test' for application package 'cl.teknopartner.beacon_test'.  isMainProcess=true
>   D/BeaconParser( 7818): Parsing beacon layout: m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25
>   I/flutter ( 7818): Beacon scanner initialized
>   D/FlutterBeaconPlugin( 7818): START RANGING=[{identifier=com.beacon}]
>   I/CycledLeScanner( 7818): This is Android 5.0.  We are using new scanning APIs
>   I/BeaconService( 7818): beaconService version 2.16.2 is starting up on the main process
>   D/AndroidRuntime( 7818): Shutting down VM
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 7818): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 7818): Process: cl.teknopartner.beacon_test, PID: 7818
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 7818): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager;
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 7818):    at org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconLocalBroadcastProcessor.unregister(BeaconLocalBroadcastProcessor.java:82)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 7818):    at org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconLocalBroadcastProcessor.register(BeaconLocalBroadcastProcessor.java:74)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 7818):    at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.BeaconService.ensureNotificationProcessorSetup(BeaconService.java:257)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 7818):    at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.BeaconService.onCreate(BeaconService.java:219)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 7818):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3163)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 7818):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:177)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 7818):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1513)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 7818):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 7818):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 7818):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 7818):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 7818):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 7818):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 7818):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 7818): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/cl.teknopartner.beacon_test-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/cl.teknopartner.beacon_test-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 7818):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 7818):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 7818):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 7818):    ... 14 more
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 7818):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 7818):        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 7818):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 7818):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 7818):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 7818):        ... 15 more
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 7818):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
>   I/Process ( 7818): Sending signal. PID: 7818 SIG: 9
>   Lost connection to device.

Si alguien me puede orientar, o quizá indicarme algún tutorial sobre este teme (lo he buscado sin éxito), se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: No parece que ese sea el error real, parece un mensaje de advertencia. ¿No te salen más trazas de error? ¿Puedes incrementar el nivel del log por si sale algo más?

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: hola, agregué el código que estoy ejecutando. Lo volví a correr y no me sale la advertencia que puse antes, lo cual me confunde aún más. Estoy poniendo en el mensaje original todo lo que resulta de la ejecución, lo estaba revisamdo pero no me ayuda mucho.